# What does “small way” mean?

Tags: meaning

I want to ask the meaning of this passage:

> He was falling, landing heavily on the rocks of the creek bed. He lay there, gulping in the sweet air among the rocks. He must carry on down, even a **small way**. Anything to escape the suffocating darkness. He drew in more air, then picked himself up and set off a stumbling path over the broken ground.

It’s a scene about a forest fire.

In that sentence, what does *small way* mean? Does it mean small distance or small road?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "a small way" means "a short distance".

Comment: The driveby downvoter strikes again. What's the problem here? The answer is correct.